# Adding Events to .NET Sockets in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, events

I have a CustomSocket class that extends the Socket that adds events to get some feedback about clients disconnecting from a server. I am wondering how to add my client disconnect method to the event delegate if the _listenerSocket.Accept() method returns a Socket and not my CustomSocket class which has the events in it?? The code is as below.

```
   public class CustomSocket : Socket
{
    private readonly Timer timer;
    private const int INTERVAL = 1000;
    public delegate void SocketEventHandler(Socket socket);

    public CustomSocket(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType) : base(addressFamily, socketType, protocolType)
    {
        timer = new Timer { Interval = INTERVAL };
        timer.Elapsed += TimerTick;
    }

    public CustomSocket(SocketInformation socketInformation) : base(socketInformation)
    {
        timer = new Timer { Interval = INTERVAL };
        timer.Elapsed += TimerTick;
    }

    private readonly List<SocketEventHandler> onCloseHandlers = new List<SocketEventHandler>();
    public event SocketEventHandler SocketClosed
    {
        add { onCloseHandlers.Add(value); }
        remove { onCloseHandlers.Remove(value); }
    }

    public bool EventsEnabled
    {
        set
        {
            if (value)
                timer.Start();
            else
                timer.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Connected)
        {
            foreach (var socketEventHandler in onCloseHandlers)
                socketEventHandler.Invoke(this);
            EventsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    // Hiding base connected property
    public new bool Connected
    {
        get
        {
            bool part1 = Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
            bool part2 = (Available == 0);
            if (part1 & part2)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }

}
```

I was thinking that I would want to add for events on the Socket that is returned from the Socket.Accept(); method except that this is a Socket is not a CustomSocket so there there are no events. I think I going about this the wrong way.

```
       static void ListenThread()
    {
        try
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                _listenerSocket.Listen(5);
                _clients.Add(new ClientData(_listenerSocket.Accept()));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

I tried this

```
        static void ListenThread()
    {
        try
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                _listenerSocket.Listen(5);
                CustomSocket cs = (CustomSocket) _listenerSocket.Accept();
                _clients.Add(new ClientData(cs));
                cs.SocketClosed += CsOnSocketClosed;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

But I get casting errors etc..
Any help would be appreciated..

Matt

Comment: Would you like to post the exact error message?

Comment: ... and indicate in your code when the casting (and other) errors occur?

Comment: Here is a copy of the exception.
+  $exception {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket' to type 'ServerApp.CustomSocket'."} System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}

Comment: In my project im trying to add nodes to a treeview as clients connect to the server and then remove the nodes when the disconnect. There will be more than one client connecting to the socket therefore I thought I needed to catch the event that came from the socket object that was passed back from the Socket.Accept(); method

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a Socket to a CustomSocket. Because Accept returns a Socket and not a CustomSocket.

You could wrap a Socket in a CustomSocket which takes a Socket as parameter like this to solve your issue.

```
class CustomSocket
{
  private Socket _socket;
  public Socket Socket
  {
    get
    {
      return _socket;
    }
  }

  public CustomSocket(Socket s)
  {
    _socket = s;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use composition instead of inheritance for this, due to the fact that the `Accept()` method will never return an instance of your own class. See existing socket wrappers like `TcpClient`, `NetworkStream`, etc. for inspiration. There's not enough detail here to be able to provide specific guidance as to how to compose your `Socket` instance. However, for dealing with the `Accept()` method scenario specifically, it would look something like this:

```
class CustomSocket
{
    private Socket _socket;

    public CustomSocket(Socket socket)
    {
        _socket = socket;
    }

    public CustomSocket Accept()
    {
        return new CustomSocket(_socket.Accept());
    }
}
```

Finally, it's not entirely clear what the overall goal in sub-classing/wrapping the `Socket` class here is, but the code you posted so far looks like you are trying to abstract a polling mechanism on the `Socket` class.

But polling a `Socket` is the least efficient way to use it, and is unnecessary. You may find that by using the asynchronous model with the `Socket` (e.g. `Socket.BeginAccept()`, `...BeginRead()`, etc.) that you don't need to abstract anything, and that you can use the `Socket` class directly.